# ReactJS App on Tomcat

Tags: java, reactjs, tomcat, server, webpack

I created a ReactJS Webapp Frontend with Webpack on Port: 8081
To start the app I use the command at the main folder:

```
npm start
```

My Java-Backend runs on a Tomcat-Server on Port: 8080. The Backend provides my REST-APIs which were called by the Frontend.

How is it possible to set up my ReactJS App on the same Tomcat Server?

Comment: it would be better to have your front-end app served by an apache server and your back-end app served by a tomcat. If you want to redeploy the front app you don't need to stop the tomcat. If you still want a single app, you just need to add the html/js/css files generated by webpack at the root of your war file

Comment: what backend framework do you use?

Comment: @oliv37 where do i find these generated files from webpack?

Comment: @Chilliggo I think you have a command to build your project like `npm build` which will build your project, generally it produces a `dist` folder where you can find the generated files

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **frontend-maven-plugin** from eirslett in your pom file download location https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin

This plugin will download Node and NPM into the node directory of the Java project.  The plugin will then use NPM to download all of the Javascript libraries defined in the project.json file (including Webpack) into the node_modules directory.

For more detail refer following article. 
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-use-reactjs-java-web-applications-edward-mostrom

Sample React + java web app is available at https://github.com/emmostrom/JavaReact